# Iterating through Array of objects containing arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

```js
 const endpoint =
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FormidableLabs/radon-typeahead/master/demo/car-models.json';
      const cars = [];
      //fetch the data on the cars, convert the json raw into json and the add it to the array cars
      fetch(endpoint)
        .then((blob) => blob.json())
        .then((data) => cars.push(...data));

      function findMatches(wordToMatch, cars) {
        return cars.filter((Carbrand) => {
          //check if the brand matches what was searched
          //create a regular expression
          const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
          return Carbrand.brand.match(regex);
        });
      }

      function displayMatches() {
        const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, cars);
        const htmlCars = matchArray
          .map((carBrand) => {
            return `
            <li>${carBrand.brand}</li>
          `;
          })
          .join('');

        const htmlModels = matchArray.map((carBrands) => {
          carBrands.models.map((carModels) => {
            //return carModels + 'this';
            //console.log('li ' + carModels);
            return
            `
            <li>${carModels}</li>
            `;
          });
        });
        console.log('htmlModels ' + htmlModels);
        suggestions.innerHTML = htmlCars + htmlModels;
      }

      const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
      const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

      searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches);
      searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Car filter</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald" />
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0" />
  </head>
  <style></style>
  <body>
    <form class="search-form">
      <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="City or State" />
      <ul class="suggestions">
        <li>Filter for a car</li>
        <li>or a state</li>
      </ul>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to iterate through and array made of objects that contain keys and Arrays. I'm nesting a map function to display an array that is in the object. I'm trying to get it in a html list `<li>`

Here is an example of the object.

```
{
    "brand": "Acura",
    "models": [
      "2.2CL",
      "2.3CL",
      "3.0CL",
      "3.2CL",
      "ILX",
      "Integra",
      "Legend",
      "MDX",
      "NSX",
      "RDX",
      "3.5 RL",
      "RL",
      "RSX",
      "SLX",
      "2.5TL",
      "3.2TL",
      "TL",
      "TSX",
      "Vigor",
      "ZDX"
    ]
```

The first part getting the car brand works, I'm just struggling to get it to display the models that are in an array.

If I console.log 'carModels'I can see the models as strings but trying to return them is not working. I see `,,,,,,` in my console.

`findMatches` returns an array of matches which works fine.

What I am trying to do is display results for a car brand and then in a nested list all the models of that brand, using a nested map inside my function. Its's working when console logging but I cant seem to return the results.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` stack snippet editor to make a [mcve] - it is hard to guess how and where you execute the code since your displayMatches is incomplete

Comment: I've edited your post to remove references to JSON, since JSON is a text format, like CSV. There is no such thing as a "JSON object" or "JSON array". By the time you're iterating, it's no longer JSON.

Comment: You are not returning anything inside `matchArray.map((carBrands)`. So `htmlModels` will not have the value which you are expecting.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to return <li>carModel</li>.

Comment: @Delon carBrands.models.map((carModels) => {  `return` carBrands.models.map((carModels) => { }}

Comment: Just tried that, seems to return an empty array

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I managed to get it right, the problem was converting the returned arrays to strings using join().

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const cars = {
  "ACURA" : [
    "2.2CL",
    "2.3CL",
    "3.0CL",
    "3.2CL",
    "ILX",
    "Integra",
    "Legend",
    "MDX",
    "NSX",
    "RDX",
    "3.5 RL",
    "RL",
    "RSX",
    "SLX",
    "2.5TL",
    "3.2TL",
    "TL",
    "TSX",
    "Vigor",
    "ZDX"
  ],
  BMW : [ 318, 320, 428 ]
}

function displayMatches() {
  let carLI = [];
  let modelLI = [];
  Object.keys(cars)
    .filter(car => car.indexOf(this.value.toUpperCase())===0)
    .forEach(car => { console.log(car)
      carLI.push(`<li>${car}</li>`);
      modelLI = cars[car].map(model => `<li>${model}</li>`);
    })

  document.getElementById("cars").innerHTML=carLI.join("");
  document.getElementById("models").innerHTML=modelLI.join("");
}

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("input",displayMatches)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off"/>
<ul id="cars"></ul>
<ul id="models"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, trying to wrap my head around it, I'm trying to understand why my nested map is not working when I can see the strings if I use console.log.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it right

```js
const htmlModels = matchArray
  .map((carBrand) => {
    return carBrand.models
      .map((model) => {
        //console.log(model);
        return '<li>' + model + '</li>';
      })
      .join(' ');
  })
  .join(' ');
```